# Options to ppPasteOLEObject when creating dynamic PowerPoint decks? (HUGE file size)

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I switched from using ppPasteEnhancedMetafile to ppPasteOLEObject when creating a PowerPoint deck based on an Excel file.

*Set grph = myPresentation.Slides(x).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=10, Link:=msoFalse)*

As I'm copying about 60 different dynamically created tables from Excel into PowerPoint, I need to retain the ability to do a final edit in PowerPoint which using the metafile option doesn't give me.

Problem is, the file jumped from 254KB in size to 234,464KB in size doing this.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Pasting as an OLE object will embed a copy of the *entire* source XL file in your PowerPoint.  And again for each add'l embedded OLE object.

It might work better for you to create a LINK to the XL info instead.  That will remain editable for final edits, but once you break the link (explicitly, or by ungrouping the XL content in PPT, or by simply not providing the linked XL file along with the PPT/PPTX) the recipient won't be able to edit the XL data; for all intents and purposes they'll have only a metafile picture to look at.